# Optimal setup for Multi Domain Wordpress with Woocommerce

Tags: multisite, woocommerce-offtopic, database, domain-mapping

I have the task of setting up five Woo Commerce stores. The issue i am facing is that all the sites must have separate domain names, require separate themes and should all propagate products from the same database ( With the intention of updating inventory across all stores ).

I've attempted setting up a multi-site network with domain mapping utilities but it seems to have just created sub-domains off of the main.

Would gladly appreciate any advice or direction.

Answer (score 0):

So, as a word of warning, WooCommerce doesn't officially support multisites that draw from the same product database. Some (a lot) of extensions won't work correctly, so just a heads up on that aspect.

It sounds like a good workaround would be to install the five sites separately, and have them all connect to the same database software. Square, for example, has database and inventory capabilities - if they all connected to the same Square account then they could draw from the same inventory.

The best solution would be to link it to an external database, and you could use the [WooCommerce REST API](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/) to build out any connection to another service if it's not available on the WooCommerce.com extension catalog.